# S3 Object: Difference between 'expires' and 'expiration date'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am attempting to follow AWS documentation for `aws s3 cp`, which [documents the `--expires` flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) as:

> --expires (string) The date and time at which the object is no longer cacheable.

...

> Copying a local file to S3 with an expiration date
>
> The following cp command copies a single file to a specified bucket and key that expires at the specified ISO 8601 timestamp:
>
> aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt --expires 2014-10-01T20:30:00Z

So, when I run a command just like the example above, I wind up with a file in S3 which has an "Overview" pane on the right side which looks like this:

[image: overview pane]

The overview pane claims there is no "Expiration date". OK. But if I click through to the file, under Properties -> Metadata, I do see this:

[image: S3 Object Metadata]

So which one is right? Do the 'Expires' and 'Expiration date' timestamps mean different things somehow? Or are they the same thing, and the display is just buggy?

I have searched StackOverflow for several similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010718/set-aws-s3-expiration-for-specific-file), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643328/amazon-s3-expiration-date), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164849/amazon-s3-object-expiration) ) but didn't find this question answered.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So, this is extremely poorly documented, but I think I found an answer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3):

> To add a Cache-Control or Expires header field to Amazon S3 objects using the Amazon S3 console ...
>
> Choose **Add Metadata**, and then in the **Key** menu, choose **Cache-Control** or **Expires**. ...
>
> For an **Expires** field, type a date and time in HTML format.

In other words, the **Expires** field that one sets via `aws s3 cp ... --expires=...` is intended to be an HTTP header which influences downstream caches (apparently CloudFront will honor this `expires` value). The S3 object is **not deleted** after this time.

Confusingly, this **Expires** value is completely different from the **Expiration** of an S3 object, which I gather can [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010718/set-aws-s3-expiration-for-specific-file) [be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185879/s3-per-object-expiry) by a [Lifecycle Policy on the S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html), not per-file at upload time (i.e. not using `aws s3 cp ...` ).

Comment: @mauriblint I think you're asking whether it's possible to set a per-object **Expiration** . I think you could do this with different Lifecycle policies applying to different path prefixes, but that would involve inventing some path scheme, e.g. `/objects/under/here/expire/after/1month`, `/objects/under/here/expire/after/1year`/ and embedding this in the Lifecycle rule. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html

Comment: JFC how do I get back the afternoon I spent chasing my own tail bc of this