# AWS Powershell "Write-S3Object" fails, but "aws s3 cp" succeeds w/ Expires header

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I am trying to upload a file to S3 w/ Expires metadata.  This is from Windows using Powershell 7.

This command succeeds using the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 cp myFile.xml "s3://my-bucket/myFile.xml" --content-type "text/xml" --region "us-east-1" --expires "2024-01-01" --cache-control "max-age=60"
```

And the Content-Type, Cache-Control and Expires headers are all set the way I expect them to be.

However, when I use AWS Tools for Powershell's Write-S3Object, it fails:

```
Write-S3Object  -BucketName "my-bucket" -File myFile.xml -ContentType "text/xml"  -Key "myFile.xml" -Region "us-east-1" -HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "max-age=60"; "Expires"="2024-01-01"}
```

The error is:

> Write-S3Object: The request signature we calculated does not match the
> signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

It's because of that Expires header.  If I leave that off the Write-S3Object command, it works.

I've tried setting the Expires date in the future, the past, changing the format, etc.  Nothing works.

If I add any other header other than Cache-Control to that header collection, I get the same error.  If I leave off Cache-Control and just specify Expires, I get the same error.

Are these two commands as equivalent as I think they are?

BTW I found this post but it didn't seem helpful to my situation: [Amazon S3 - How to fix 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/amazon-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-s)

Comment: Possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917188/s3-object-difference-between-expires-and-expiration-date).

Comment: I don't use the PowerShell variant of awscli. Wonder if you need to use `-Metadata` for the expires value?

Comment: What are you wanting the `expires` date to do? Are you wanting the object to be deleted, or do you want browsers to stop caching it? This might be helpful: [S3 Object: Difference between 'expires' and 'expiration date'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917447/174777)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Tools for PowerShell does work when you specify an `HTTP-date` per [RFC 7231 section 7.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

This works for me with version 4.1.517:

```
Write-S3Object  -BucketName "my-bucket" -File myFile.xml -ContentType "text/xml"  -Key "myFile.xml" -Region "us-east-1" -HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "max-age=60"; "Expires"="Mon, 01 Jan 2024 05:00:00 GMT"}
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/434 is tracking this inconsistency across the different AWS SDKs and console.